# What is causing the window coordinate vector to not project properly?

Tags: animation, texturing, camera, tracking

I'm trying to project a frame onto an object so it would look like a hatch is in the ground of my tracked video. Seems like the frame is a bit disproportionate.
[image]

Scale of the object is applied.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone has the same issue, I found the answer. So this was filmed with a phone and it could be that the dimensions weren't quite right so my camera cropped a bit of the video. So that was pretty much it.